# How many solutions does the equation $x + y + w + z = 15$ have if $x, y, w, z$ are all non-negative integers?

Tags: combinatorics

Combinatorics Question:

> How many solutions does the equation $x + y + w + z = 15$ have if $x, y, w, z$ are all non-negative integers?

What I tried for solving this problem is $$\binom{16 - 1 + 4}{4}$$

I got $16$ from the numbers $0$ thought $16$ as possible values for $x, y , w$ or $z$.

However apparently the answer is $$\binom{16 - 1 + 3}{3}$$ Can someone explain to me where this $3$ is coming from since there are $4$ variables $x, y, w, z$.

Comment: Have you searched for similar problems and their solutions ?  There are plenty

Comment: Hint: Suppose you have 15 one dollar bills and 4 people. How many ways are there to divide the bills?

Comment: The answer is $\binom{15+4-1}{4-1}$, or equivalently $\binom{15+4-1}{15}$.  Look at the Wikipedia article on Stars and Bars.  It is all too easy to be off by one on top and bottom. The way I usually get around that problem is to figure out the answer each time instead of trying to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Think of $15$ as a sequence of stars. You can insert $3$ bars in any position between them to get a solution, for example $0+3+10+2$ would be represented this way:
$$|\star\star\star|\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star\star|\star\star$$

It should be clear than any permutation of those stars and bars (which is the name of this method by the way) represents a valid solution, so that the total is given by $\frac{18!}{15!3!}$ (permutation of $18$ objects divides in $2$ groups of indistinguishable objects with $15$ and $3$ elements respectively), which, as someone wrote in the comment, is the same as $\binom{15+4-1}{4-1}$

In general stars and bars gives $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ as the number of ways to pick $k$ nonnegative numbers so that their sum is $n$. I personally find it easier to think about it as permutations of stars and bars for a specific case than to remember the general formula

Answer (score 1):

The way I remember it is to put the number of $+'s$ at the bottom,
and add it to the required total at top, hence simply $\dbinom{15+3}{3}$

And if the requirement is for positive integers, preplace $1's$ for each variable,
and apply the same formula, so $\dbinom{11+3}{3}$